# Using Elasticsearch bucket_script in Grafana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, grafana

I have an Elasticsearch query to track %age of 50x hits from Elasticsearch Logstash indexes.

I would like to implement this in Grafana, but I can't find any good docs or examples of how to configure this query via the UI. The UI apparently does support `bucket_script`, but it's not clear how to implement.

The ES query is:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "all_hits" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "@timestamp",
                "interval": "day"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "total_hits": {
                    "value_count": {
                        "field": "http_status_code"
                    }
                },
                "50x": {
                  "filter": {
                    "terms": {
                      "http_status_code": [500,501,502,503,504]
                    }
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "hits": {
                      "value_count": {
                        "field": "http_status_code"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                "error_rate": {
                    "bucket_script": {
                        "buckets_path": {
                          "total_hits": "total_hits",
                          "error_hits": "50x>hits"
                        },
                        "script": "params.error_hits / params.total_hits * 100"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```